# JUnit Scheduler that doesn't depend on Android

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java, android-testing, rx-android

I´m trying to use MVP to enhance unit testing and run tests faster (because I'm testing logic not android code so I avoid using things like RobotElectric).

But I´m using RXAndroid and it needs Looper to get `Schedulers.io()` and `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` and when I try to run sometime like

```
class Phone {
    public Observable<> sendSms(String number){
        //...
    }
}

Phone.getInstance().sendSms(phoneNumber)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(phone -> {
                    mView.dismissProgress();
                    mView.startCodeView(phone);
                }, error -> {
                    mView.dismissProgress();
                    mView.showError(error);
                });
```

I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
at rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.<clinit>(AndroidSchedulers.java:27)
... 28 more
```

I tried:

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

But it will not work because I want to run full JUnit tests and not Roboelectric or Espresso stuff.

How can I accomplish it? is there any Scheduler that will not crash because of this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am also using scheduler thread for this, but in my test SetUp and TearDown.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
}
```

Will this help?

Comment: is there any hook for Schedulers.io() ?

Comment: There is RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().register... too :)

Comment: @danielgomezrico yes but I haven't used it though, if you have can you put insight or edit answer

Comment: @danielgomezrico why you want to need hook for io? and yes RxJavaPlugins has that

Comment: bc I use it too so I need to use "immediate" in those cases for tests

Answer (score 5):

I ended up adding using transformations and "flavour injection classes" for this, have a class that uses the main for prod/debug releases and use another class in the test flavour folder for testing `Schedulers.immediate()`.

normal flavoured class:

```
public class Transformer {

  public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyIoSchedulers() {
    return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(getIoScheduler())
        .observeOn(getMainScheduler());
  }

  private static Scheduler getIoScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.io();
  }

  private static Scheduler getMainScheduler() {
    return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
  }
}
```

Testing flavoured class:

```
public class Transformer {

  public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyIoSchedulers() {
    return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(getIoScheduler())
        .observeOn(getMainScheduler());
  }

  private static Scheduler getIoScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.immediate() ;
  }

  private static Scheduler getMainScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.immediate() ;
  }
}
```

Then use it with transformations:

```
mSessionRepository.login(...)
        .compose(Transformer.applyIoSchedulers())
        .subscribe(session -> { })
```

Answer (score 3):

In our practice, we try to avoid using `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` in Presenter because it's a detail of `View` implementation. You can do this too.

Though we use Robolectric, so anyway it'll work in our tests.

Comment: I am a little sceptic about Roboeletric, I ended up using Immediate Scheduler for testing.

Comment: @danielgomezrico how did you use Immediate scheduler for testing? Are you still using AndroidScheduelrs.mainThread() outside of tests? How are you making the distiction? Thanks

Comment: @drees I`m using flavour injection classes, I have a class that uses the main for prod/debug releases and use another class in the flavour folder for testing. Im still using  Schedulers.immediate() for testing yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, no android.jar in junit tests means no Loopers.  If you use Dagger you can inject a mock scheduler into tests and a real scheduler into source code.  You could also use something like Mockito to mock the Scheduler.  Otherwise like @Artem Zinnatullin suggested, Robolectric solves this problem.  Robolectric 3 is very easy to setup with Android Studio.